# Отправка письма с кнопкой submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

Нужно отправить письмо с текстом, по клику на кнопку

```js
<?php
$to      = 'anna@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Hello ' . $_GET['aics_subject'];
$message = ''. $_GET['aics_name'] . $_GET['aics_phone'] . $_GET['aics_message'] . $_GET['aics_email'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

```html
<div id="wish_list" class="wish_list">
  <form id="form-mail" action="mail.php" class="prog_bron prog_bron-pb">
    <div class="prog_bron-pb-in">
      <input id="aics_name-s" type="text" name="aics_name" placeholder="Имя, Фамилия">
      <input id="aics_email-s" type="text" name="aics_email" placeholder="email">
      <input id="aics_phone-s" type="text" name="aics_phone" placeholder="Телефон">
      <input id="aics_subject-s" type="text" name="aics_subject" placeholder="Выбор">
      <textarea id="aics_message-s" name="aics_message" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Комментарии"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="prog_bron-btn">
      <input id="aiContactSafeSendButton-s" type="submit" value="ХОЧУ ПОЕХАТЬ">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

первый раз делаю подобное. В общем, даже не понимаю как это закончить.
форму я сделал, но не понимаю как это все связать вместе и что б оно работало.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: С прибытием на Стак :)

Answer (score -1):

mail.php

```
<?php

function sendmail($mail, $theme, $message, $from="robot@domain.com") {

    settype($mail,    "string");
    settype($theme,   "string");
    settype($message, "string");

    $message = str_ireplace(array('\\r','\\n'), array('', '\n'), $message);

    # headers
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "From: Name Surname <{$from}>\n content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\n";
    $headers .= "X-Sender: <no-reply@damain.com>\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: damain.com \n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: <no-replay@damain.com>";

    # send email message
    mb_send_mail($mail,$theme,$message,$headers);
}

$mail    = 'anna@gmail.com';
$theme   = 'Hello ' . $_GET['aics_subject'];
$message = "Name: ". $_GET['aics_name'] ."\n Phone". $_GET['aics_phone'] . "\n";
$message .= "Message: " . $_GET['aics_message'] . "\nE-Mail:" . $_GET['aics_email'];

sendmail($mail, $theme, $message);
```

HTML не стал описывать. Должно все заработать. Но вообще передавать данные методом GET не стоит. Вот тут есть пошаговая статейка:
https://webriz.ru/25-prosteyshaya-forma-otpravki-dannyh-na-pochtu-pri-pomoschi-html-i-php.html

Единственное что рекомендую для отправки самого письма использовать предложенную мной sendmail()